# React-router not loading css for nested pages on refresh

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to setup a `react-router` for my first React webapp, it seems to be working except that the css doesn't load for my nested pages when I refresh the pages.

However it works for just one level e.g `/dashboard` but the css won't load for `/components/timer`

Here is what my `index.jsx` file looks like

```
import './assets/plugins/morris/morris.css';
import './assets/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './assets/css/core.css';
import './assets/css/components.css';
import './assets/css/icons.css';
import './assets/css/pages.css';
import './assets/css/menu.css';
import './assets/css/responsive.css';

render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Dashboard}/>
    <Route path="/components/:name" component={WidgetComponent}/>
    <Route path="*" component={Dashboard}/>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Are you getting 404s on those .css files when you reload? Is your web server pointing all `/` and `/components/:name` to your index.js where you load react and all related files?

Comment: @JorgeObregon am getting 404, it tries to load the css and scripts as `http://localhost:3000/components/assets/js/jquery.slimscroll.js` instead of `http://localhost:3000/assets/js/jquery.slimscroll.js`

Comment: @JorgeObregon how do I point my webserver to `/components/:name`?

Comment: it depends on the webserver you are using. Apache uses .htaccess file for pretty links, while ExpressJS uses a RegExp to match your routes

Comment: @AdetiloyePhilipKehinde How did you solve this?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I had this problem too, where my app wasn't loading style sheets and the like. However, I was importing my assets directly into my `index.html` entry point.

By replacing the links with absolute paths as per [this documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/FAQ.md#why-doesnt-my-application-work-when-loading-nested-routes), my problem was resolved.

For me, this meant changing

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" ></link>
</head>
```

to this:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" ></link>
</head>
```

I'm not sure if the same thing would work for your import statements, but it is worth a shot.

FYI I'm using the project layout from `create-react-app`.

Comment: Thanks sonarforte, for those using Webpack with the ```html webpack plugin``` to generate your index.html files I was able to solve this issue by telling Webpack where to place the output file in my config file. The object looked like this: 
`output: { publicPath: "/" }`

Comment: worked for me! it was all about removing the dot before the path....

Answer (score 40):

Found it!

Add the HTML Element:

```
<base href="/" /> <!-- for local host -->
```

to your index page to set a base case for your URL so all else will follow suite.

Comment: Worked for me as of 10/2020

Comment: Perfect solution for nextjs or any folder structure architecture

Answer (score 16):

I added

```
<base href="/" /> <!-- for local host -->
```

to my index.html head

And it is resolved.

Answer (score 7):

The *simplest solution* is here (Need to change index.html only)

Just use `%PUBLIC_URL%` before every CSS or JS file.

You can check an example of `%PUBLIC_URL%` in `index.html` file if you created react app through `create-react-app`.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
```

**One thing is must: your CSS files and js files should be under a public directory.**

Answer (score 6):

If you are using create-react-app workflow, put the assets under public folder and use the special variable  PUBLIC_URL.

Inside index.html use %PUBLIC_URL%:

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">`

Inside JS/JSX files use process.env.PUBLIC_URL:

`render() {
  // Note: this is an escape hatch and should be used sparingly!
  // Normally we recommend using import for getting asset URLs
  // as described in “Adding Images and Fonts” above this section.
  return <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/img/logo.png'} />;
}`

**Recommended Approach**:
 import stylesheets, images, and fonts from JavaScript by placing it along with src files.

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.png'; // Tell Webpack this JS file uses this image

console.log(logo); // /logo.84287d09.png

function Header() {
   // Import result is the URL of your image
   return <img src={logo} alt="Logo" />;
}

export default Header;
```

[Adding assets to public folder](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#using-the-public-folder)

[When to use public folder](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#when-to-use-the-public-folder)

Answer (score 1):

I know its a bit old thread, but ill share my solution here. Its a solution for setup that uses `webpack` instead `create-react-app`.

I found every other solution suggests to change the `<link` path in the html file. But like in my case `webpack` handles the asset linking.

I faced the same problem today. Routes like `/some_route` works but - `/some_route/second_level` it doesn't, leaving behind a message in console stating -

**`Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/some_route/some_style.css'`**.

I fixed this problem by updating my **`webpack.config.js`** file

```
output: {
    filename: 'build.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
    publicPath: '/',         ////// <-- By adding this line
}
```

Hope it helps someone. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see a webpack,config.js

Comment: Sry, but this is the `output` configuration part of `webpack.config.js`. The rest of the webpack.config.js is not the subject

Answer (score 0):

Your script is not loading your css due to the 404 errors. Your webserver is not redirecting all `/components/*` request to index file and then routing to your view via react.

But now, specifically about fixing your css issues... In the past, I've struggled with the css imports in jsx files, so you are not alone :) Instead, I've chosen to use SASS or LESS to compile my css to a `bundle.css` file with grunt or gulp. Then load that `bundle.css` directly on my `index.html` file. One neat trick about using css compilers is every time you change a .scss or .less file, your `bundle.css` will get updated.

Hope I pointed you in the right direction.

Cheers,

Comment: thanks Jorge but loading bundle.css won't solve the problem of webserver not redirecting `/components/*` to index file ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is weird , but if you use history@5.0.0 ,delete it and install history@4.10.1
react-router have many incompatibilities with history version 5 .
for me it's worked.