# Why does React keep setting cookie to other path when page refresh?

Tags: reactjs, cookies

There are main page["/"] and sub pages["/admin/lines", "/admin/line:{idx}"] and I set "access_token" cookie to login when I logged in and it works fine.

There are access token cookie and Path is "/" in [F12 - Application - Cookies] but when I refresh in the **sub pages** (not main page) there is another same access_token created but path is /subpage like this screenshot:

[image]

The problem is that new access_token other Path Value is none so page keeped route to login page.

Why does this same token keep showing?

Answer (score 1):

add to index.html header:

```
<base href="/" /> <!-- for local host -->
```

[Based on this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40426011/react-router-not-loading-css-for-nested-pages-on-refresh)